Laravel 11.21 server.php File Missing After Running php artisan serve — How to Resolve?
Why the server.php given by laravel is being deleted when i exit the terminal in VS code or in CMD i currrently using
xampp
php v8.2.12
composer v2.7.6
laravel framework v11.21.0
i try to uninstall and reinstall the php, composer, and laravel multiple times

server.php has been moved inside the framework in Laravel 9.
It is correct that it does not exist.
https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/40034
https://github.com/laravel/laravel/pull/5747
